# Sonar Issue: Remove this "\", add another "\" to escape it, or make this a raw string

Tags: python, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, pylint

There is a rule in SonaeQube/SonarLint/SonarSource for backslashes:-

```
"\" should only be used as an escape character outside of raw strings

[https://rules.sonarsource.com/python/RSPEC-1717][1]
```

So now i am using regular expression like this :-

```
re= '\{(\d+)[,\-](\d+)\}': # Numbered pattern
```

SonarQube is giving issue is like : Remove this "\", add another "\" to escape it, or make this a raw string.

I cannot avoid the use of backslashes here, Please Suggest me how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do as the suggestion says.

Option 1: escape the escape characters with an additional `\`

```
re = '\\{(\d+)[,\\-](\\d+)\\}'
```

Option 2: make it a raw string

```
re = r'\{(\d+)[,\-](\d+)\}'
```

In this case, option 2 requires less changes (only the `r` prefix) and is easier to read.

Comment: Dose it make any effect in our pattern??

Comment: Option 1 and Option 2 are equal. If you look at the output of ``print( '\\{(\d+)[,\\-](\\d+)\\}' )`` and ``print( r'\{(\d+)[,\-](\d+)\}' )`` you will see that internally it's the same string ``\{(\d+)[,\-](\d+)\}``